# Count number of occurrences before a certain value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to count of how many times "Agent" rows appears with 2 or more "Threading" on top of it.

In the below example, the count is 2 as row 3 (Agent) has 2 threading on top and row 7 (Agent) has got 3 threading on top. The order is determined by the date column.

[image]

Any idea how to get the count?

Below is code I am using:

```
DECLARE @INFO AS TABLE
(
    Process VARCHAR(10) ,
    Content VARCHAR(100) ,
    Date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @INFO
(
    Process,
    Content ,
    Date
)
VALUES
('Threading', 'Content A', GETDATE() - 9), ('Threading', 'Content B', GETDATE() - 8), ('Agent', 'Content C', GETDATE() - 7), ('Threading', 'Content D', GETDATE() - 6), ('Threading', 'Content E', GETDATE() - 5), ('Threading', 'Content F', GETDATE() - 4), ('Agent', 'Content G', GETDATE() - 3), ('Threading', 'Content H', GETDATE() - 2), ('Agent', 'Content I', GETDATE() - 1)

SELECT * FROM @INFO AS i

-- Result it 2.
```

Comment: What denotes the order of your data? There's no obvious always ascending value, making this task impossible.

Comment: Good point. I have updated by example. Its ordered by date column.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use a windowed `COUNT` to put the rows into groups, based on how many times `'Agent'` has appeared *prior* to the row. Then you can `COUNT` how many `'Threading'`s are in each group, and then finally `COUNT` how many of those groups have a value of 2 or more:

```sql
WITH Grps AS (
    SELECT Process,
           Date,
           COUNT(CASE Process WHEN 'Agent' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Grp
    FROM @INFO),
Counts AS(
    SELECT COUNT(CASE Process WHEN 'Threading' THEN 1 END) AS Threadings,
           Grp
    FROM Grps
    GROUP By Grp)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Counts
WHERE Threadings >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I am using the LAG function to get the second last and last process per row.

```
SELECT  * , LAG(i.Process, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY i.Date) lastProcess,  LAG(i.Process, 2) OVER ( ORDER BY i.Date) secondlast
FROM    @INFO AS i
```